# Why can I compile PDFLaTeX if the pdf is open in Sumatra but not if it is open in most other readers?

Tags: compiling, viewers, acrobat, sumatrapdf

If I compile a .tex document using PDFLatex (i.e. the compilation ultimately produces a .pdf), and I have a pdf of the same name open in Adobe Acrobat, the compile will throw an error, asking for a different name for the output .pdf. However, if I attempt to accomplish the same task with the document open in Sumatra, the compilation happens without a problem, and the .pdf refreshes in Sumatra.

Obviously, this is something about the way the two different programs work. I assume that for some reason Sumatra loads a version of the file into memory, but then closes the file allowing it to be edited by LaTeX, while Acrobat keeps the file open. Why the difference? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach? Most .pdf readers seem to handle .pdfs like Acrobat, but are there others who do it like Sumatra?

Comment: Adobe reader locks the file, essentially making it read only, for other programs. Since Adobe reader/acrobat can edit the file, it makes sense to not allow others that access when the file is open.

Comment: @daleif It's only the Windows operating system which has this ridiculous concept of file locks at all.

Comment: @HenriMenke doesn't it lock on mac as well?

Comment: NOTE there is a working unlocked cache limit of 10Mb beyond which even SumatraPDF will need the PDF to be closed before a fresh compile. However if the file is the same name then with forward search it should open at the same location if remember settings is on. So if you have a large PDF file (due to high density images) it may be worth using image placeholders until the final compile.

Comment: @KJO " there is a working unlocked cache limit of 10Mb ... "Are you sure? I've recently created a 46Mb PDF viewed with Sumatra (v3.1.2 64-bit Windows) with no apparent problems when recompiling it while viewing it.

Comment: @alephzero Main cause is from code snippet #define MAX_MEMORY_FILE_SIZE (10 * 1024 * 1024) Your mileage may vary, since it can be affected by networked location etc however for a similar user experience see https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/auto-reload-of-pdf-no-longer-works/796

Comment: I haven't even downloaded the source, so I definitely haven't tweaked anything. I downloaded the Windows executable, and it "just works" - for me, at least. There is no networking involved either - everything is on my PC disks. I'm talking about re-creating the PDF in TeX though, not trying to save it from Adobe Reader while it is open in Sumatra. Personally I would guess this is "just another bug in Adobe Reader..." which is why I switched to Sumatra in the first place!

Comment: @alephzero If you have a 9MB file some editors will update on the fly, Sumatra sees the data change and can auto refresh the screen, in some of those cases as it goes over 10Mb it may need a trigger of the R key to force reload when you do a full compile SumatraPDF is instructed to "reuse" the same filename that was already open thus it may differ for some editors. But without some testing in each editor I don't know who may or may not be be affected

Comment: It seems that this is about as good an answer as I am likely to get. If one of you wants to post an answer for the points, I'll choose it.

Comment: I think since your question was widespread about how different viewers behave it would be of value to others to answer what you learnt from these comments, links, experiences and summarize your own user conclusions  for your specific usage.

Answer (score 3):

This is now a super old question, but I have an answer that merits inclusion.

1. Why does Sumatra allow you to compile a file while open? Because Sumatra loads the file and works on the loaded version of the file, rather than locking the current file to prevent conflicts. For Sumatra, this isn't much  of a problem, because you cannot really edit the file in Sumatra, but is probably not possible without creating conflicts in files you can edit.
2. Are there other readers that behave the same way? Yes! Okular, which has most of the utility of Sumatra *and* you can include comments *and* it works on Linux, Windows and Mac. In general, Okular is an *amazing* FOSS program.